# Trying to figure out a fitting function for a curve where the fitting function always passes through the origin (0,0)

Tags: curves

I have a curve that looks like this.

[image: Acceleration v Velocity]
Acceleration v Velocity

I am trying to figure out a function I can use to fit to this curve. I have tried using a curve of the form $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ and while that does a good job of fitting the points it does not go through the origin. I am trying to construct a function of some sort that fits the points in the image and also goes through or is as close to the origin as possible.

I'd really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: Could you post the data ?

Comment: The curve rises to its peak in a horizontal distance of $\sim 3$, but it takes $\sim 6$ to fall back down. Quadratics rise and fall at the same speed, so this is not quadratic behavior. Have you tried best-fitting a cubic instead? Is there anything about the set up that might suggest a different behavior? For example, the right most points hint that maybe instead of dropping back to $0$, the curve may flatten out and approach $y = 0$ asymptotically as $x \to \infty$. If that is the case, then no polynomial would be a good fit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes here it is x = [0,0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25,6.75, 7.25, 7.75, 8.25, 8.75]
y= [0,3.5576, 5.3968, 6.4948, 7.8348, 8.5732, 9.024,  8.9168, 8.892,7.882,7.398,  5.5616, 4.0944, 2.7836, 1.65,1.0352 ,0.6656 ,0.7936, 0.436 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We observe that the function is on the power kind for small $x$ :

[image]

This draw us to look for a function of this kind :
$$y(x)=x^p f(x)$$
With $p\simeq 0.4$ :

[image]

The curve $f(x)$ appears like a piecewise linear function :

$$f(x)\simeq c+(ax+b)\text{H}(x-r)$$
H is the Heaviside step function.

In order to have a smooth transition between the two linear functions one can replace the Heaviside function by an approximate function of the logistic kind.
$$H(X)\simeq \frac{1}{1+e^{-q\,X}}$$
So, the function considered is :
$$y(x)=x^p\left(\frac{ax+b}{1+e^{-q\,(x-r)}}+c \right)$$

Then the parameters are computed thanks to non-linear regression :

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is wonderful! I greatly appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the graph of a polynomial to go through the origin, omit the constant term. For your quadratic polynomial, omit $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Second degree best fit
$$f(x)=3.65823 x-0.235842 x^2$$
Third degree
$$g(x)=0.0197976 x^3-0.673543 x^2+5.83586 x$$

[image]

Comment: That really helps! Thank you very much!